# scala playframework returning Ok in flatMap

Tags: scala, playframework

i have the following function:

```
def createProcessTemplate: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
    println(request.body.asJson)
    request.body.asJson.map(_.validate[ProcessTemplatesModel] match {
      case JsSuccess(process, _) =>
        processTemplateDTO.createProcessTemplate(process).map {
          process => {

            // Create process steps templates
            createNewProcessStepTemplate(request, process.id.get)


            // Create prerequisites
            createProcessTemplatePrerequisite(request, process.id.get)

            // Create postConditions
            createProcessTemplatePostCondition(request, process.id.get)

            processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplates(process.id.get).flatMap(
              steps => Ok(Json.obj("id" -> process.id, "title" -> process.title, "steps" -> steps)))
          }
        }
      case JsError(_) =>
        Future.successful(BadRequest("Process Template not create client"))
      case _ => Future.successful(BadRequest("Process Template create client"))
    }).getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest("Process Template create client")))
  }
```

I want to return the steps in the Ok Statement, but got this error:

[image]

what could be the problem in this case?

thanks

Comment: ``flatMap`` expects a ``Future[T]`` but you're returning only an ``Ok``. Try to wrap to it in ``Future.successful``

Comment: like this: `processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplates(process.id.get).flatMap(
              steps => Future.successful(Ok(Json.obj("id" -> process.id, "title" -> process.title, "steps" -> steps))))`

Comment: got the same error

Comment: What do `processTemplateDTO.createProcessTemplate(process)` and `processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplates(process.id.get)` return?

Comment: `processTemplateDTO.createProcessTemplate(process)` returns Future[ProcessTemplatesModel]

Comment: `processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplates(process.id.get)` returns Future[Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
def createProcessTemplate: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
println(request.body.asJson)
request.body.asJson.map(_.validate[ProcessTemplatesModel] match {
  case JsSuccess(process, _) =>
    processTemplateDTO.createProcessTemplate(process).flatMap {
      process => {

        // Create process steps templates
        createNewProcessStepTemplate(request, process.id.get)


        // Create prerequisites
        createProcessTemplatePrerequisite(request, process.id.get)

        // Create postConditions
        createProcessTemplatePostCondition(request, process.id.get)

        processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplates(process.id.get).map(
          steps => Ok(Json.obj("id" -> process.id, "title" -> process.title, "steps" -> steps)))
      }
    }
  case JsError(_) =>
    Future.successful(BadRequest("Process Template not create client"))
  case _ => Future.successful(BadRequest("Process Template create client"))
}).getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest("Process Template create client")))
```

}

I've switched the `map` and `flatMap` that appear around calls to `processTemplateDTO` methods. In the first one you need `flatMap` because you return a `Future`, but in the second one you actually want a `map` because you return a `Result`.

Comment: No problem :) Happy to hear that I helped.